# ActiveRecord foreign keys not being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to save a simple object with keys into two other existing objects. Here's the object:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :User, :autosave => true
  belongs_to :Comment, :autosave => true
end
```

I thought creating one of these would be as simple as

```
@uls = Tag.create(:Comment => @comment, :User => current_user )
@uls.save
```

This saves the tag correctly, but the user_id and comment_id fields are never set, they're always null. What is the correct command to get the foreign keys to save?

Comment: lowercase `belongs_to :user`, same for comment

Comment: Thanks! Write that up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lowercase `belongs_to :user`, same for comment